# Wifi on Lenovo N581 blocks other wifi clients

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

I have a problem with the wifi on my new **Lenovo IdeaPad N581**: the wifi works after installing the additional drivers, but when I switch it on all other computers connected to our wifi router (the french freebox), I have no internet access anymore.

If I boot windows it works fine. The card is a **broadcom BCM4313 802.11bgn**, the driver shown by lsmod is cfg80211 or wl.

Comment: That's wacky. It sounds like a great weapon!

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct driver for your device is not wl but brcmsmac. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get reomve --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

It may take a reboot. Is the behavior improved?

Get brcmsmac to load on boot with:

```
 sudo -i
 echo brcmsmac >> /etc/modules
 exit
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, actually not... I did as you proposed, then the others had a connection, but very slow, then I rebooted and had no wifi anymore... Reinstalled the recommended one by Additional Drivers and the story started from the beginning... :-(

Comment: So,clearly the one suggested by Additional Drivers,bcmwl-kernel-source, is incorrect, no? A slow connection with brcmsmac is another question.

Comment: I now installed this one: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211 , following the instructions on that site including removing the driver from the blacklist. Now I get the Wireless Network Authentication Required window, but even with correct key it does not connect...

Comment: lspci says now Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge, Kernel modules: bcma

Comment: What does this tell us? lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43 -e brcm